# CoreData string being replaced by placeholder text on app restart

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to save a string to a CoreData data model. I believe the saving process works normally, however, I have made a `text` variable which just holds a placeholder message before a user saves a string to the database. On app restart, any messages saved will be replaced by the placeholder text again, losing any saved messages created in the previous session.

`ClientData` is the name of the Entity, and `presetMessage` is the Attribute inside. `presetMessage`'s type is `String`.

ClientData+CoreDataClass.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(ClientData)
    public class ClientData: NSManagedObject {

    @objc (setMessage:)
    public func setMessage(_ presetMessage: String?) {
    }

}
```

ClientData+CoreDataProperties.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension ClientData {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ClientData>{
        return NSFetchRequest<ClientData>(entityName: "ClientData")
    }

    @NSManaged public var presetMessage: String?

}
```

ViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

var text = "Placeholder Text"

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var messageSaved = [ClientData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ClientData> = ClientData.fetchRequest()

              do {
                  let messageSaved = try PersistenceServce.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                  self.messageSaved = messageSaved
              } catch let error as NSError {
                  print("Error: \(error.domain)")
              }

    }    

    @IBAction func onEditMessageTap(_ sender: Any) {

   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Edit Preset Message", message: "Enter a new preset message", preferredStyle: .alert)
             alertController.addTextField { textfield in
                 textfield.placeholder = "Your message..."
             }
             alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { action in
                 text = alertController.textFields!.first!.text!
                let savedMessage = ClientData(context: PersistenceServce.context)
                savedMessage.presetMessage = text
                PersistenceServce.saveContext()
                self.messageSaved.append(savedMessage)

                    return
             }))
             self.present(alertController, animated: true)

      }
}
```

`PersistenceServce` prints `SAVED` when the `alertController` finishes with a string, indicating that it has completed its process without any errors.

Edit: Source Code: https://github.com/SamuelMereau/coredata-error-reproduce

Comment: can you make a reproduction project and upload this to github?

Comment: @J.Doe Done. I added the GitHub URL to the question (see edit). It contains all necessary files. If you plug them into Xcode with a blank project it should reproduce the issue.

Comment: I mean the whole project, so if you can create a brand new project, put those files inside the project and set the whole project on github, it takes everyone just a second to have a reproduction project, now I need to do all the work and everyone else